# Netsh command not found on Azure server

Tags: azure, netsh

I have a Microsoft Azure server and I need the netsh command, but netsh.exe is not where I would expect it. I've tried creaing an Administrator powershell session, and an administrator CMD session. I have checked in the C:\windows and C:\windows\system directories.

How do I get the netsh command on an Azure server?

Comment: netsh should be in `C:\Windows\System32`. I can run in from both a command prompt and from Powershell in a Windows Server 2019 VM in Azure. What exactly happens when you try to run it?

Comment: I get a command not found error. It's as if the file doesn't exist.